# Can “so” mean “as per”?

Tags: meaning

I see that there a separate discussions on *so* and so many meanings of *so* are discussed, but I would like to know if *so* can also mean *as per?*

I was reading [Euronews Online](http://de.euronews.com/2014/09/30/schwacher-herbst-auf-dem-deutschen-arbeitsmarkt/) and I came across the following statement :

> Die Arbeitslosenquote nahm um 0,2 Punkte auf 6,5 Prozent ab, so die Bundesagentur für Arbeit.

I assume it means *as per* or *according to BfA* – is that correct? Does the dictionary list this meaning of so?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa#Bedeutung1b

Comment: I would explain: "so ist die Meldung der BAA" or "so meldet es die BAA".

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it can be used as "according to", but this usage is mostly found in news reports, and it can only be used **after** the statement.

For example, you could *not* say

> "So die Bundesagentur für Arbeit, nahm die Arbeitslosenquote um 0,2 Punkte auf 6,5 Prozent ab."

"So" essentialy means "like this", so literally it would be

> "The unemployment rate declined by 0.2 to a value of 6.5%, (saying it) **"like this"** (/according to) the Federal Employment Agency."

If more citations follow, there can also be a **"weiter"** (continuing/further) added. As in

> Die Zahlen des nächsten Monats werden bald vorliegen, so die Agentur weiter.
>
> The values of next month will soon be available, "so" the agency "continues/further".

You wouldn't use it like this in a conversation, as it's a typical news report phrasing.

To say "according to" it's more common to use "laut" + Gentitv or Dativ (according to Duden, both is OK), which is used before the statement. As in

> "Laut der Bundesagentur für Arbeit nahm die Arbeitslosenquote um 0,2 Punkte auf 6,5 Prozent ab."

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the German 'so' can also mean 'as per / according to'.

From [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/so.html):

[image: so [laut] - according to {prep} [reporting a person's opinion, e.g. no news can be expected according to the president]]

Answer (score 4):

*So* can also be used to report direct quotations (in quotation marks). In such cases it’s best translated as *said.* This example from today’s Spiegel Online:

> “Der große Unterschied ist, dass der IS als Terroristengruppe geführt wird”, so de Bruin.
>   “The big difference is that the IS is operated like a terror group”, said de Bruin.

*According to* or *as per* would sound odd in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means *according to* and is frequently found in written German.