# Was bedeutet „ ,Zitat', so jmd.“

Tags: meaning

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   [Can “so” mean “as per”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17238/can-so-mean-as-per)

Ich sehe ab und zu die folgende Verwendung des Wortes „so“:

> Die zwei Formulierungen zeigten Erdogans politische Mentalität, sagt
>   der türkische Politikwissenschaftler Ertug Tombuş: Erdogans
>   politisches Denken gründe auf Ungleichheit und einer Hierarchie;
>   jegliche Verpflichtung zu Pluralismus und Demokratie fehlten, **so
>   Tombuş.**

Ich habe eine grobe Idee aus dem Kontext, was „so Tombus“ bedeuten soll, trotzdem wollte ich genau wissen, was es bedeutet.

Dieses Zitat lässt sich [hier](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/wie-der-tuerkische-praesident-die-opposition-verfolgen-laesst-13349039.html) finden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa#Bedeutung1b) handelt es sich bei dieser Verwendung des Adverbs *so* um eine Ellipse, bei der das Verb eingespart wurde.

> …, so [sagte] Tombuş.

Diese Form wird bei Zitaten oder Quellenangaben verwendet und bedeutet zum Beispiel

> …, mit diesen Worten äußerte sich Tombuş. *(bei wörtlichen Zitaten)*
>   …, in diesem Sinne äußerte sich Tombuş. *(bei sinngemäßen Wiedergaben)*

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, es handelt sich dabei um die Kurzform von "so sagte XY" oder "so berichtet CNN" – auf Englisch würde man vielleicht sagen "according to XY".